# Run and sync threads on Android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer, chronometer

I use countdown timer, which starts `Chronometer`:

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, countDownInterval)
{
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        countDownTimer.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished + 1000) / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish()
    {
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronometer.start();
    }
}.start();
```

And `metronome`:

```
private void playMetronome()
{
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            metronome.play();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I want to start metronome with a countdown timer and play metronome when the chronometer is working. When I compile this code I get out of sync in a few seconds.

How can I sync countdown timer with metronome and chronometer?

Comment: could you explain this  lil further? "I get out of sync in a few seconds"

Comment: I start timer and metronome at the same time (e.x. 60bpm metronome/1 bit 1 second). After a minute or later I get the metronome sound out of sync. The timer is rushing or lagging behind the metronome sound.